# Script to extract text using grep

Tags: scripts, grep, xml

I am trying to extract two text strings from multiple data files in a directory. I want to separate the text string using a ~ character and send the output to one single file.

Example
directory name: `/xmldocs`   AND the filenames are name of files: `1.xml`, `2.xml`, `3.xml`

Expected Output:

```
TEXT_STRING_ONE~TEXT_STRING_TWO   ------- This is from 1.xml
TEXT_STRING_ONE~TEXT_STRING_TWO   ------- This is from 2.xml
TEXT_STRING_ONE~TEXT_STRING_TWO   ------- This is from 3.xml
```

SCRIPT used kind of works with only one grep command

```
for i in `ls`
do
grep "Document ID:" $i
echo "~" 
echo "\n"
done >> /xmldocs/1.txt
```

When I insert the 2nd grep command; `grep 'CI[^"]'`   the script hangs and there is no output.

Current Output is

```
<KMS_data id="KMS_documentId" name="Document ID:">12</KMS_data>
~
<KMS_data id="KMS_documentId" name="Document ID:">19</KMS_data>
~
<KMS_data id="KMS_documentId" name="Document ID:">6</KMS_data>
~


grep "Document ID:" $i
~


grep "Document ID:" $i
~


grep "Document ID:" $i > /xmldocs/1.txt
~
```

Any help is appreciative. I am very very new with LINUX/UNIX commands and I need to extract the information from 20,000 xml files. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post a sample data file ?

Comment: As @Serg said, we need an input file example.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is process the result from grep and append it explicitly to the output file. This way you can use the console to write debug messages.

```
#/bin/bash

# Save output to this file
outputFile='./xmldocs/1.txt'
rm -f $outputFile

# List only *.xml files and iterate
for i in `ls *.xml`
do
    # Echo which file is being processed (only printed to console )
    echo 'Processing :'$i
    # Grep, remove trailing newline and append to $outputFile
    grep "Document ID:" -s $i | tr -d '\n'  >> $outputFile
    # Add char to separate
    printf "~" >> $outputFile
    # Grep, remove trailing newline and append to $outputFile
    grep 'CI[^"]' -s $i | tr -d '\n' >> $outputFile
    # Print newline to separate results
    printf "\n" >> $outputFile
done 

echo '!! done'
```

If this don't work please post the other line that you want to grep to test it.

Comment: Hi bistoco. Thanks very much. Your code worked very well.  I have tweak a bit on the second grep statement. The idea is to extract text starting from CI and end till the next word is Summary.  I'll do research on the net on how to do this. But as far as the code goes, it is working fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why the script may be hanging with your use of `grep 'CI[^"]'`, you should be escaping ^. Using `grep 'CI[\^"]'` fixed the issue for me. This is because the carrot symbol, even within the scope of brackets, is interpreted as negation.

EDIT: Steeldriver's correction

Comment: Hi aJetHorn. Thanks for the tip. I now realized why it hung. Cheers!

Comment: Actually a *leading* caret within a character set or range acts as a negation operator (rather than a line anchor) i.e. `[^"]` means 'any character except `"`: you can avoid that interpretation just by reversing the order `["^]`

Comment: Hi steeldriver, Thanks for the explanation. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `paste`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.xml
do
    paste -d '~' <(grep 'Document ID:' "$f") <(grep 'CI[\^"]' "$f")
done > /xmldocs/1.txt
```